# Can I say "I ask me questions" instead of "I ask myself question"?

Tags: reflexive-pronouns

Can I say "I ask me questions" instead of "I ask myself question"? Is using reflexive pronouns mandatory?

Comment: Mandatory if you don't want to sound like someone who doesn't speak English very well.

Comment: I don't think even the most obscure dialects would allow ***me*** there. You'll certainly hear dialectal / uneducated things like ***I sat me down on a church pew*** instead of ***I sat myself down***, but for some reason that doesn't sound so likely with a verb like ***ask.*** But I don't know what underlying principles affect how idiomatic it is to use a non-reflexive pronoun in contexts where "standard" English uses the reflexive form, so it's an interesting question.

Comment: In some English dialects, *"I ask me questions"* would in fact be understood as *"I ask **my** questions"*. E.g., *"I ask me questions and they give their answers"*.

Comment: @WillVousden: That's quite true. But "there" in my comment meant ***in that context*** (i.e. - *with that intended meaning*, rather than *with those 4 words as a credible utterance*).

Comment: Instead, you may simply say "I question myself".

Answer (score 0):

No.

When the speaker both performs **and** receives the verb’s action, you must use the *reflexive* pronoun 'myself'.

'Me' can be used as an object pronoun when someone else is performing the action (eg "*he asked me*").

Comment: Idiomatically, many people are perfectly happy with ***I bought me some chocolate*** in informal contexts, but I'm not sure anyone would go along with ***I asked me some searching questions***. But in both those cases, it seems fair to say the subject both performs and "receives" the verb’s action. So although from a strict grammar perspective, "subject is both agent **and** patient" is probably what defines "valid" usage, there's something else in play with certain informal usages.

Comment: Note that neither _You bought you some chocolate_ nor _He bought him some chocolate_ seems idiomatic (in that meaning) to me. I think we have an idiom here _I [verb] me [object]_: the tense is not fixed, and the verb is somewhat variable, though not freely; but the _me_ is fixed, though I'm not certain whether _We bought us some chocolate_ works or not. I've a feeling that ditransitive verbs are not allowed: it has to be a transitive verb with _me_ as a benefactive.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm aware that might be used in some southern dialects of US English but it's colloquial and certainly not taught as correct in schools.

Comment: @ColinFine "he bought him some chocolate" is only idiomatic if there are two persons. If it's the same person it would be "he bought himself some chocolate".

Comment: I think the "superfluous possessive" of *I'm gonna **drink me** some beer, I just **love me** some fried chicken* is more stereotypically AAVE throughout the US, rather than being *geographically* dialectal. Those usages rarely if ever get the full reflexive pronoun, though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers right but we teach English here, not cultural appropriation or mimicry of African American dialects

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Those put me in mind of "Thou art like one of those fellows that when he
enters the confines of a tavern claps me his sword
upon the table" (_Romeo & Juliet_, III 1)

Comment: @Astralbee: that's why I said "in that meaning".

Comment: So strictly speaking, the reflexive pronouns need to be used if the subject and the indirect object mean the same thing or person in the form of "Subject + Verb + Indirect Object +Direct object Object." Thank you for all the answers!